# Count specific value for IDs in two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, group-by

I have two dataframes

**df1**

```
+----+-------+
|    |   Key |
|----+-------|
|  0 |    30 |
|  1 |    31 |
|  2 |    32 |
|  3 |    33 |
|  4 |    34 |
|  5 |    35 |
+----+-------+
```

**df2**

```
+----+-------+--------+
|    |   Key | Test   |
|----+-------+--------|
|  0 |    30 | Test4  |
|  1 |    30 | Test5  |
|  2 |    30 | Test6  |
|  3 |    31 | Test4  |
|  4 |    31 | Test5  |
|  5 |    31 | Test6  |
|  6 |    32 | Test3  |
|  7 |    33 | Test3  |
|  8 |    33 | Test3  |
|  9 |    34 | Test1  |
| 10 |    34 | Test1  |
| 11 |    34 | Test2  |
| 12 |    34 | Test3  |
| 13 |    34 | Test3  |
| 14 |    34 | Test3  |
| 15 |    35 | Test3  |
| 16 |    35 | Test3  |
| 17 |    35 | Test3  |
| 18 |    35 | Test3  |
| 19 |    35 | Test3  |
+----+-------+--------+
```

I want to count how many times each `Test` is listed for each `Key`.

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    |   Key | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test4 | Test5 | Test6 |
|----+-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|  0 |    30 |       |       |       |   1   |   1   |   1   |
|  1 |    31 |       |       |       |   1   |   1   |   1   |
|  2 |    32 |       |       |   1   |       |       |       |
|  3 |    33 |       |       |   2   |       |       |       |
|  4 |    34 |   2   |   1   |   3   |       |       |       |
|  5 |    35 |       |       |   5   |       |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**What I've tried**

Using join and groupby, I first got the count for each `Key`, regardless of `Test`.

```
result_df = df1.join(df2.groupby('Key').size().rename('Count'), on='Key')


+----+-------+---------+
|    |   Key |   Count |
|----+-------+---------|
|  0 |    30 |       3 |
|  1 |    31 |       3 |
|  2 |    32 |       1 |
|  3 |    33 |       2 |
|  4 |    34 |       6 |
|  5 |    35 |       5 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

I tried to group the `Key` with the `Test`

```
result_df = df1.join(df2.groupby(['Key', 'Test']).size().rename('Count'), on='Key')
```

but this returns an error

`ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df2.Key,df2.Test).reindex(df1.Key).replace({0:''})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution with groupby & pivot. Using this solution you don't need df1 at all.

```
# | create some dummy data
tests = ['Test' + str(i) for i in range(1,7)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': np.random.choice(tests, size=100), 'Key': np.random.randint(30, 35, size=100)})
df['Count Variable'] = 1

# | group & count aggregation
df = df.groupby(['Key', 'Test']).count()
df = df.pivot(index="Key", columns="Test", values="Count Variable").reset_index()
```